# Powershell v2.0 on Linux TERM environment variable not set

Tags: linux, azure-devops, powershell-2.0

I am running Powershell v2.* on VSTS **Hosted Ubuntu 1604**

I get **TERM environment variable not set.**

Here is my code.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

```
$env:TERM="xterm"

function Update-Tokens()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$filePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$tokensStartingWith
    )

    Write-Host -Fore Yellow "Replacing Tokens";

    $fileContents = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filePath)


    foreach($theEnv in (Get-ChildItem env:* | sort-object Name)){
        if($theEnv.Name.StartsWith($tokensStartingWith))
        {
            Write-Host -Fore Yellow "Updating: $($theEnv.Name)=$($theEnv.Value)"
            $fileContents = $fileContents.Replace("`${$($theEnv.Name)}", $theEnv.Value)
        }
    }

    $fileContents | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -filePath $filePath | Out-Null
    Write-Host -Fore Yellow $fileContents

}
cls
Update-Tokens -filePath "./azure-support-ticket-k8s.yaml"-tokensStartingWith "SUPPORT_TICKET_BUILD_" | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to remove the **cls** statement!
Also, you don't need the **$env:TERM="xterm"** statement (remove it).
This is OK on a Windows hosted agent, but falls over on Linux.  Something to do with the terminal not being able to clear screen when running a non-interactive script.